# The server is not operational. Error from AD when asp.net application is hosted in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory

I hope i can get a help from someone.
I have an asp.net application i host in sharepoint in the Layouts folder.
The app checks if a user s password has been updated or expired.
When i first deployed the application it all worked well but later i started getting error The server is not operational.
Any ideas and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the proble in nothing to do with sharepoint basically its AD problem kindly go through the following link

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223321

Comment: Thanks but the only temp solution i have now is to recycle the app pool of the application